# How to force a groupby/sum when summing on a mismatched value in a column in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe 'df':

> data = {'first':['jack','jack','zeke','zeke','zeke'],
> 'last':['sparr','sparr','smith','smith','smith'],
> 'method':['cell','cell','skype','cell','cell'], 'duration':
> [5,5,3,1,1]}

```
first     last     method    duration
 jack    sparr       cell           5
 jack    sparr       cell           5
 zeke    smith       skype          3
 zeke    smith       cell           1
 zeke    smith       cell           1
```

I want to sum the call durations on first, last, and method. I'd like it so when the 'method' doesn't match, they are 'force summed' and the value is left blank

So far running a something like:

> df = df.groupby(['first','last','method'], as_index=False).sum()

will give back:

```
first     last     method    duration
 jack    sparr       cell          10
 zeke    smith       skype          3
 zeke    smith       cell           2
```

but I'm going for

```
first     last     method    duration
 jack    sparr       cell          10
 zeke    smith                      5
```

How can I modify my sum statement to achieve this, or is this even possible with pandas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df.groupby(['first', 'last'], as_index=False)[['method', 'duration']]\
  .agg({'method':lambda x: x.iloc[0] if x.nunique() == 1 else '', 
        'duration':'sum'})
```

Output:

```
  first   last method  duration
0  jack  sparr   cell        10
1  zeke  smith                5
```

Okay, let's group by only first and last name since you sums appear to at this level.   For method, we are going aggregate to one value, if all the values in the method column the same (nunique == 1), else use '' blank.

We are using dictionary to define the aggregation of each column.

Comment: thanks! can you explain how you knew to chain these things together and what the thought process is? that statement is intimidating haha :0